# Restore files and database wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to transfer my website to a new server. I didn't know about appropriate way of taking backup. I copied all files inside `public_html` and exported database from `phpMyAdmin`. Now I am trying to restore files and database.

I just copied all files in public_html and made database and imported. Now I'm getting `HTTP Error 500`. Please tell me how can I restore these files without losing data.

Comment: is the domain name same?

Comment: @Azmat Yes domain name is same.

Comment: can you please send the URL of your site? and CPanel in my email if possible?

Comment: @Azmat Site is www.nepalichristians.com , I want to know, is this right way to restore?

Comment: That's not wrong way but not good for non-technical users.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing site transfer using cPanel, then you need to keep the following in mind. I may also suggest to use a plugin like Duplicator or so if doing manually is too much of work for you. Let's see how you can do a manual transfer.

**Current Server**

1. Assuming all your files are in `public_html` directory, compress them all using cPanel compress feature. Once done, you will something like `wp-admin.zip` in your `public_html` directory.

Download the `wp-admin.zip` file in your computer.

2. Visit `phpMyAdmin` and locate your site DB. Let's call this `wp_current_server`. On the database screen where you can see all your DB tables for your `wp_current_server` DB, hit Export button and hit Go. No other step is needed there.

After a few seconds an SQL file will be downloaded on your computer.

So, now you have all your files in the `wp-admin.zip` and DB in the `wp_current_server.sql` file.

**New Server**

3. Login to your new server cPanel and locate `public_html` directory. Assuming the entire directory is empty, just upload your `wp-admin.zip` file there.

Once uploaded, use the **Extract** feature in the cPanel and decompress `wp-admin.zip` file. After that you will see all your WP folders and files like *wp-admin, wp-includes, wp-content* and so.

Now you can safely delete your `wp-admin.zip` file from your server.

4. Move to Database section in your cPanel and create a new DB. Give a name to your DB, create a DB username and add a password. Keep note of all them in a text file like notepad. You will need them all.

Do make sure you give all the privileges to your DB user.

5. Now hit the `phpMyAdmin` button and locate your newly created DB. It will be empty of course.

Look for the import button in the top bar and import your `wp_current_server.sql` there. Again keep the configuration default. Wait for a few seconds before the import is complete. If you domain name does not change in your new server, your job is done there. Move to the # 6 below

6. In your public_html directory, locate the wp-config.php file in the root. Open this with and find the constants like *db_name, db_username, db_password*. Fill in these all correctly from your saved notepad. Save the file and then visit your site. You're done.

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @Ayanize , Thanks for your elaboration. I have no more access to old server. I copied all the files from public_html and downloaded mysql database. I did not compress them, just right clicked on public_html and downloaded via FileZilla. How can I manage them now?

Comment: No problem. If you have all the files and db in .sql format, then you can do the rest 3, 4, 5, 6 steps. Try them